# fsockopen(): unable to connect when using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, fsockopen

I am required to get domain information so I wrote this function

```
 $servers = array(
    "biz" => "whois.neulevel.biz",
    "com" => "whois.internic.net",

function whois($domainName, $ext)
{
$server = trim($this->servers[$ext]);

    $output = "";

    try {
        if ($conn = fsockopen($server, 43)) {
            fputs($conn, strtolower($domainName) . '.' . $ext . "\r\n");
            while (!feof($conn)) {
                $output .= fgets($conn, 128);
            }
            fclose($conn);
            if (stristr($output, "No match") ||
                stristr($output, "No Data") ||
                stristr($output, "No entries") ||
                stristr($output, "No entries") ||
                stristr($output, "NOT FOUND")) {

                $this->durum[$ext]["durum"] = "bos";


            } else {
                $this->durum[$ext]["durum"] = "dolu";
                //  $this->durum[$ext]["son"] =substr($output)

            }


            $bas = strpos($output, "Expiry Date:");
            $t = substr($output, $bas, 23);
            $tarih = str_replace("Expiry Date:", "", $t);

            $this->durum[$ext]["son"] = $tarih;

        } else {

        }

    } catch (exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

this function works  fine  without using ajax The problem is if I use ajax I realized that Its not working second time without waiting 10 or 15 seconds.

this my ajax code

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "islem.php",
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#table').html("")
                $('.load').show()
            },

            data: {
                extension:myCheckboxes,domainName:domainName },

            success:function (e) {
             $('#table').html(e)


            }
```

Am I missin out something Why should I  wait to execute second time

Comment: The title says it's unable to connect, but the question says that it takes 10-15 seconds. Which is it? How are you calling this code when you're not using AJAX? Are you using it from the CLI or from a regular form submission?

Comment: If it's from CLI, you probably have different `php.ini` settings for CLI and web.

Comment: @Barmar I am  calling the function in the same page (for testing purpose )

Comment: So both cases go through the webserver. There's no reason why ajax should be slower.

Comment: what could be wrong with the web server

Comment: No idea. Do you see any warnings in the log? Does it say how long the server took to respond?

Comment: thanks I will check